# Job application question

Tags: work-experience, california

I have a little bit of a unique and awkward situation I need help with.

Last year I was working two part time jobs as a walk on coach at two schools at the same time. I was working probably 6 hours a week at each school. I was not under any contract.

I was fired from one of them for something in my past that didn’t happen while I was employed with the school. I wasn’t given anything in writing, but they did let me go in person.  Long story short, I did something immature in college and someone told on me. Luckily for me, the person who told on me contacted me and I was able to apologize and get the situation cleared with them.

Anyway, this was a crazy blessing in disguise, because I had a teaching credential and was not using If. So, now I’m going to apply to credentialed jobs.

I am looking at one job application, and it says to list “work experience.” Since it doesn’t ask for “work history” or “list all jobs you’ve had in the past 3 years,” could I leave the job that I was fired at off, and just list the other job?

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: please add the location where this is happening. Is background check normally conducted or not?

Comment: California and yes background checks take place.

Comment: Many employers request on job applications or background screening submissions to voluntarily list any time you have been fired and any time you have been convicted of a crime. Keep that in mind - even if the job app you're looking at doesn't ask for that, you may be asked for it as part of the hiring process, at which point it may look strange that you left it off initially.

Comment: I passed all background checks and was never asked about it.

Answer (score 1):

Was this 'walk on coach' position paid?

If yes, recommend leaving it on, but adding some verbage to the effect of 'walk on' to emphasize the informal nature of the position.   Especially in teaching/coaching where people are expected to have a lot of .1 or .2-time positions.  Also if they gave you nothing in writing there's a chance that they have nothing on file, so if asked about it they might not even know.

If no, recommend leaving it on as a resume line under volunteer work and stating nothing about the dismissal, as people expect turbulence and short terms for volunteer work.

I'd do a little research of whether this 'something in my past' is going to appear in background checks (Michael's comment above) and whether this will affect your future employment searches, and if yes nail down a way to handle it when it comes up again.

Good luck.